# Will I Be Able to Manipulate Excel Data in AWS Python Lambda Function

Tags: python, excel, lambda

I will be writing a function in AWS Lambda using Python 2.7 that does the following:

1. Grabs a stored Excel file from Amazon s3.
2. Opens the Excel file.
3. Manipulates data in multiple Excel sheets rows of data that will eventually be inserted into an RDS instance.
4. Repeats the process once a day at the same time.

Locally, I have written and tested the script with no issues.  My only concern is whether or not the script will open the Excel file if it's not stored locally.  Can anyone shed light?

Here is some of my code (there's much more)- excel functions are used with the xlrd package:

```
import boto
from boto.s3.key import Key
import datetime
import requests
import xlrd

""" Get the Key object of the given key, in the bucket """
k2 = Key(bucketName,"srcFileName.xlsx")

"""Get the contents of the key into a file """
k2.get_contents_to_filename("destFileName.xlsx")

"""Open the file."""
fl = xlrd.open_workbook(destFileName)

"""Access the sheet specified"""
sh = fl.sheet_by_name(sheet_names[0])
```

When the code finishes running the k2.get_contents_to_filname() function, it writes the excel file to the current working directory on my computer.  When I open the file to manipulate using the functions in variables 'fl' and 'sh' is it calling the file stored locally or has the python session stored it in memory to be accessed?  If it can only be accessed from local storage, how do I handle opening the file for manipulation in Lambda?

Thanks.